# Delete remote configuration variable in GIT

Tags: git, github

I need to remove the remote variable called `original` for reuse. I know the variable is stored in the directory `.git/.conf`

This is what the terminal shows in Linux:

```
git remote add original6 https://github.com/perez/git.git
remote original6 already exists
```

Comment: Please the variable is called original6

Comment: git config --unset [variable name]           I found it in INTERNET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git remote rename original6 newname
```

Should be the command you're looking for. This will allow you to rename the old remote to something else and add a new remote named original6.

If you want to delete the remote, type:

```
git config -e
```

And manually delete the listing from your config file.

There should be an entry that looks like this:

```
[remote "original6"]
    url = somebody@somewhere.com:something.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/......
```

If you delete those lines from your config, you should be good to go.